# How I should to catch out_of_range exceptions?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector, palindrome, indexoutofrangeexception

I get **`out_of_range`** in my code. How I have to fix this? There are 2 functions. The first function checks a string if it is a palindrome. The second function has to find palindromes from vector and copy it to a new vector which is a return value.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool IsPalindrom(string a)
{   
    string b = a;

    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());

    if (b == a)
    {
         cout << "success " << endl;
         return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "error";
        return false;
    }
}

vector<string> PalindromFilter(vector<string> words, int minLength)
{
    vector<string> pol;

    for (int i = 0; i <= words.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (IsPalindrom(words[i]) && words[i].size() > minLength)
        {
            pol.at(i) = words.at(i);
        }
    }
    return pol;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> a = { "ama", "madam", "safg", "arnold", "dad", "dd" };

    PalindromFilter(a, 2);

}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> pol` is a zero-length vector. Clearly, any indexing using the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) method will throw an `out_of_range` error.

Comment: Aside: you don't to copy the string if you use it's `rbegin()` and `rend()` members: `bool IsPalindrome(string a) { return std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), a.rbegin(), a.rend()); }`

Comment: Aside 2: `for (string word : words)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch an exception with a `try catch` block:

```
try{
PalindromFilter(a, 2);
}
catch(const std::out_of_range& e){
  //std::cout <<"Error: "  << e.what(); //to print the exception description
  //or do whatever
}
```

However this doesn't make your program work as it should, you need to solve your `Palindrome` method issues.

In your `for` loop, in the last iteration, your `words` vector access is **out_of_bounds**. Use `<` instead of `<=`.

This: `pol.at(i) = words.at(i);` is not valid, `pol.at(i)` doesn't exist until memory is allocated for it, you can use `vector` `push_back()` method, `pol.push_back(words[i]);`

Comment: @Leeker, you are welcome, if you feel that any of the answers satisfies your question you should [**accept it**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

You are accessing `words` out of range in the loop. Also `pol` is empty, so you need to use `push_back` to add new elements.

```
vector<string> pol;

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
{
    if (IsPalindrom(words[i]) && words[i].size() > minLength)
    {
        pol.push_back(words.at(i));
    }
}
return pol;
```